# Run query over a Array

Tags: php, find

I want to run a query over an Array or string with PHP

Let say I got a string:

```
$Iamastring = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc velit est, porta sed feugiat vitae, sodales et nisl. Suspendisse ut."
```

And I want to run a query over that string to find it:

```
"Lorem ipsum" OR ("dolor" AND "sodales")
```

In this case it would be true :). How is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regexp :) `preg_match('\(Lorem ipsum)|(dolor.+sodales)\', $matches)`. Or variations with different regexp's

Comment: This would work for the string, however you'd have to [map](http://us2.php.net/array-map) it to the array if you had an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

You would do this with a regular expression. Check out something like [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

The following should return true or false if the pattern matches:

```
preg_match ('/(Lorem ipsum)|(dolor+sodales)/' $Iamastring);
```

Answer (score 0):

RegExp is one way, though if you want to use inbuilt string functions:

```
$haystack="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc velit est, porta sed feugiat vitae, sodales et nisl. Suspendisse ut.";

if((strrpos($haystack, "Lorem Ipsum")!==false)||((strrpos($haystack, "dolor")!==false)&&(strrpos($haystack, "sales")!==false))){

// do this if true

}
```

Note that PHPs inbuilt string functions are faster than RegExps, but each approach varies in appropriateness depending on context.